# How to delete everything BUT two patterns found by regex

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to turn a couple thousand press releases on anti-ISIS airstrikes into an organized dataset. So far I've got working code to do it one at a time, but it chokes on doing more than one because of the way there's one date per N (constantly changing) number of cases.

Using `((?<=SOUTHWEST ASIA,).*(?<=-))` and `((?<=Near).*?(?=airstrik))` I can match the two things I need individually, but I can't figure out how to set it up to preserve all strings matching either of those regexes while deleting everything else.

I've tried `((?<=SOUTHWEST ASIA,).*(?<=-))|((?<=Near).*?(?=airstrik))` and `((?<=SOUTHWEST ASIA,).*(?<=-)).*((?<=Near).*?(?=airstrik))` but both of those wind up matching everything in the document.

What I'm trying to do is take the whole document and delete everything but the matching strings so I go from this:

> **November 23, 2016**
>   Military Strikes Continue Against ISIL Terrorists in Syria and Iraq
>   U.S. Central Command
>
> **SOUTHWEST ASIA, November 23, 2016** - On Nov. 22, Coalition military forces  conducted 17 strikes against ISIL terrorists in Syria and Iraq. In Syria, Coalition military forces conducted 11 strikes using attack, bomber, fighter, and remotely piloted aircraft against ISIL targets. Additionally in Iraq,  Coalition military forces conducted six strikes coordinated with and in support of the Government of Iraq using attack, bomber, fighter, and remotely piloted aircraft against ISIL targets.
>
> The following is a summary of the strikes conducted since the last press release:
>
> **Syria**
>
> - Near Abu Kamal, one strike destroyed an oil rig.
> - Near Ar Raqqah, four strikes engaged an ISIL tactical unit, destroyed two vehicles, an oil tanker truck, an oil pump, and a VBIED, and damaged a road.
>
> **Iraq**
>
> - Near Rawah, one strike engaged an ISIL tactical unit and destroyed a vehicle, a mortar system, and a weapons cache.
> - Near Mosul, four strikes engaged three ISIL tactical units, destroyed >six ISIL-held buildings, a mortar system, a vehicle, a weapons cache, a supply cache, and an artillery system, and damaged five supply routes, and a bridge.
>
> more text I don't need, about 5 exceptions where they amend previous reports I'll just fix by hand, and then the next report

To this:

```
SOUTHWEST ASIA, November 23, 2016
Near Abu Kamal, one strike
Near Ar Raqqah, four strikes
Near Rawah, one strike
Near Mosul, four strikes
SOUTHWEST ASIA, November 22, 2016
Near Abu Kamal, one strike
Near Ar Raqqah, four strikes
Near Rawah, one strike
Near Mosul, four strikes
```

I can match and pull out the dates and cities/strikes seperately, but that doesn't work for my purposes so I need to find a way to clean up the source document so it looks like the above.

Comment: Have you tried *stringr* `str_extract_all(txt, pattern)`? Or `regmatches(txt, gregexpr(your_pattern, txt, perl=TRUE))`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: To me it sounds OP is looking more for an infinite lookbehind.

Comment: You don't show an original string sample. You just show the _after_ sample. And, your regex doesn't make sense. You say you need to delete the portions except the ones you match, but you don't match anything else except what you match, so you can't delete anything. _Also, you don't want to use `.*` if there are many records._

Comment: sIn: If you read my post it's clear that's not a sample, it's an example of what I'm trying to do but haven't been able to do yet. I've added an example of the original text even though it's not really relevant at this point. I already have regexes to match the data I'm trying to keep, but pulling it out seperately didn't work so I'm trying a different approach now and attempting to delete everything except for all of the matches to either of the two regexes. The end result I'm trying to get is the mockup I posted originally.

Comment: Jan: It's more like a set of two inverted lookbehind and lookaheads. `((?<=SOUTHWEST ASIA,).*(?<=-))` always grabs the date (ie `November 23, 2016`) and `((?<=Near).*?(?=airstrik))` always grabs all cities (ie `Near Abu Kamal, one strike`) but that method didn't work. Now I'm trying to do the opposite and modify the source document by deleting everything that doesn't match either of the regexes. The idea is to have nothing but the dates and cities/strikes remaining (like the mockup at the bottom of my question).

Comment: Wiktor: You and Colin both suggested exactly what I needed. str_extract_all spat out a lot of extraneous `Character(0)` results but regmatches worked perfectly.  I'm actually surprised it wasn't Saint Wickham's package that worked best.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `str_extract_all` function from the `stringr` package, and pass it your regex.

I think if you pass your two regexes and separate them with `|`, it should work. If you need to test your regex, you can go to : https://regex101.com/

Best, 
Colin

Comment: Colburton: The link wasn't part of the answer at all. Colin's suggested answer was to try something from the stringr package and to use the two regexes with a | operator, the link was just a method of testing the regex ahead of time.

Colin's post, along with Wiktor's comment, were both completely relevant and very helpful. str_extract_all, a function I didn't know about, turned out to be exactly what I needed. It just grabbed a lot of "character(0)" vectors in addition to what I needed for some reason.